# Fatal error: Call to undefined function consultarCandidato()

Tags: php, html, funções

Alguém pode me ajudar com esse erro:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function consultarCandidato()

Meu código:

```
<html>
    <head>
        
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Perfil Candidato(a) !  </title>
        
        <!-- Referencia ao Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Referencia ao FontAwesome -->    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontes.css">
        
        
        
        
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    
       include "MenuzinCandi.php";
       include "conexao.php";
      
    
       
       $emailUsuario = $_GET['User'];
   
    $rsCandidato = consultarCandidato($vConn, $emailUsuario);
               
       
     
    while ($dadosCandi = mysqli_fetch_array($rsCandidato)){
    
    $_SESSION['Nome'] = $dadosCandi['Nome'];
    $_SESSION['Datadenascimento'] = $dadosCandi['Datadenascimento'];
    $_SESSION['CPF'] = $dadosCandi['CPF'];
    $_SESSION['endereço'] = $dadosCandi['endereço'];
    $_SESSION['cidade'] = $dadosCandi['cidade'];
    $_SESSION['estado'] = $dadosCandi['estado'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $dadosCandi['email'];
    $_SESSION['telefone'] = $dadosCandi['telefone'];
    $_SESSION['celular'] = $dadosCandi['celular'];
    $_SESSION['escolaridade'] = $dadosCandi['escolaridade'];
    $_SESSION['pretensãosalarial'] = $dadosCandi['pretensãosalarial'];
    $_SESSION['habilidades'] = $dadosCandi['habilidades'];
    $_SESSION['sobrecandidato'] = $dadosCandi['sobrecandidato'];
    $_SESSION['permissao_cand'] = $dadosCandi['permissao_cand'];
    $_SESSION['Username'] = $dadosCandi['Username'];
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $dadosCandi['senha'];
    $_SESSION['permissao'] = $dadosCandi['permissao'];
    
    
        
    ?>

        
        
        
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="container">
        
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            
        <font class="FonteTitle"> Perfil do Candidato(a) ! </font>
        
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
            
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
            Nome: <?php $dadosCandi['nome']?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
            Data de Nascimento:  <?php $dadosCandi['Datadenascimento']?>
            </div>
           
        </div>   
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-1">
            
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
            Endereço: 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
             Cidade:  
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
            Estado: 
            </div>
            
            </div>  
        
            <br>
            <br>
            
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
            
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
            E-mail: 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
            Telefone:  
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
            Celular: 
            </div> 
                  
            </div>
            
            <br>
            <hr>
            <hr>
            <br>
            
            <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
    
              <div class="col-lg-3">
       Escolaridade: 
   
            </div>      
                
             <div class="col-lg-4">
            
            </div> 
             
             <div class="col-lg-3">
        Pretensão Salarial:  
        </div> 

    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
           Curso: 
          
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            
            </div> 
        
        <div class="col-lg-3">
         Cargo:  
         
        </div> 
         </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-3">
      Previsão de término:  
       
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
       
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-3">
       Habilidades: 
       
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
            
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                
                <label> Sobre o Candidato: </label>
           
                
            </div>
            
            
            
        </div>
            
    <?php } ?>  
        
        </div>
        
    </body>
    <html
```

Minhas funções:

```
<?php 
   include "Conexao.php";


function consultarCandidato($vConn, $emailUsuario){
    
    $sqlCandidato = "Select * from candidato A, login O where '$emailUsuario' = A.email and O.email = A.email";
    $rsCandidato = mysqli_query($vConn, $sqlCandidato) or die(mysqli_error($vConn));
    
    return $rsCandidato;    
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tudo beleza? amigão muito provavelmente o arquivo php que tem "minhas funções" não está sendo incluído na página. Para confirmar use no seu código principal

```
include "MenuzinCandi.php";
include "conexao.php";
if (function_exists('consultarCandidato')) { 
   $emailUsuario = $_GET['User'];
   $rsCandidato = consultarCandidato($vConn, $emailUsuario);
}else{
   exit("php não encontrou a função")
}
```

Então basta inclui-lo, se mesmo assim não der certo experimente por a função no proprio arquivo principal, apenas para que tenha certeza que o problema é realmente o include.

Contudo você está no caminho certo, porém existe um problema mais sutil!
Você usa  "include "Conexao.php";" no arquivo principal e no arquivo com a função. recomendo que use só em um ou só em outro. de preferencia nos arquivos separados pra chamar métodos.

Espero que ajude, qualquer dúvida estou a disposição.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou aqui, tive que incluir a função direto no principal. E obrigado pela dica do include, sou iniciante no php e me ajuda mt